# Insert data with id on a table with auto-increment - WebSQL

Tags: html, sql, web-sql

I'm trying to import data into my WebSQL database. 
On my tables I have an auto-increment, which prevents me from inserting the data with a normal `insert into` query.

Is there an equivalent of `SET IDENTITY_INSERT (ON/OFF)` for WebSQL or a work around?

Thanks

Comment: WebSQL is no longer maintained by W3C (http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/). Use IndexedDB instead. http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/‎

Comment: No matter what database you have, you would probably have to use staging tables.  Turning auto-increment on and off is likely to cause problems with duplicate values in a PK field.

Comment: I did think about staging tables however if i'm not mistaken you can't turn the auto-increment on and off without recreating the table (using WebSQL). Which still leaves me with the problem of either inserting the data with the wrong id's or inserting the data with the correct id's but having to keep track of the auto-increment manually.